# How to write RedirectMatch, cut Last Words from the url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to append the admin to the end of URL

The `www.aaa.net/author/admin/page/61/admin`

To `www.aaa.net/author/admin/page/61/`

and `www.aaa.net/news1/admin`

to `www.aaa.net/news1/`

I wrote RedirectMatch

```
RedirectMatch 301 /(.*)/admin(.*) http://www.aaa.net/$1
```

But the result is `www.aaa.net/author/`

To cut the `/admin` Last Words from the url

How to write `RedirectMatch`

Comment: You say: `www.aaa.net/author/admin/page/61/admin` To `www.aaa.net/author/admin/page/61/`. Then, it does not seem you want to **append** admin to the end, but to remove it. ¿What's the correct interpretation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the URL always is of the form

`/author/admin/page/61/admin`

You can redirect like this

```
RedirectMatch 301 /((.*)/admin/(.*)/(.*)/)(.*) http://www.aaa.net/$1
```